# Gatling in Taurus with feeder

Tags: jmeter, gatling, locust, taurus

I am familiarizing myself with performance tools and I found Taurus which seems great.
I'd like to run Gatling in Taurus which is possible with executors.

However during the test a text file should be used which contains dynamic data for the tests. Gatling can do that with its feeders but is there any support in Taurus when I use Gatling?
Or is there similar support for JMeter or Locust?

I only found the following mail thread but no solution at the end.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/codename-taurus/wUxSBjWwJ5I

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Thanks,
V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into [JMeter Executor](http://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Global-Settings) it supports CSV files via `data-source` section

```
data-sources: # list of external data sources
- path/to/my.csv  # this is a shorthand form
- path: path/to/another.csv  # this is full form, path option is required
  delimiter: ';'  # CSV delimiter, auto-detected by default
  quoted: false  # allow quoted data
  loop: true  # loop over in case of end-of-file reached if true, stop thread if false
  variable-names: id,name  # delimiter-separated list of variable names, empty by default
```

See [Navigating your First Steps Using Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/navigating-your-first-steps-using-taurus) guide for more information

Comment: Thanks Dmitri! Does it mean that at the moment the JMeter executor is supported to use external file as data source?

Comment: Yes and even more than one data source if needed

Comment: Sorry Dmitri, I was lame and forgot to add the word 'only' in the question above... so the question is correctly: Does it mean that at the moment **only** the JMeter executor is supported to use external file as data source? No chance to use external file for Gatling or others? Thanks!